# How is it that negative temperature does not violate any laws?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, energy-conservation, temperature

I pose the following situation:

A paramagnetic solid, with dipoles that can only be parallel or antiparallel to a magnetic field, is at a small temperature (so most dipoles are parallel to the field). If the direction of the field is suddenly reversed, at the instant of inversion the dipoles would find themselves in a negative temperature region, eventually aligning themselves with the field and giving up energy in the process. If the field is inverted an indefinite number of times, the system would give up energy all those times.

Doesn't this imply infinite energy? What actually happens to all this energy?

Comment: See [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/623194/37364) to [Negative Temperature and bounded Energy of the Universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/623173/37364). It didn't really answer his question, but it might be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is aligned with the material, there is some potential energy $-U$. When the field is reversed, before the spins have flipped back, the energy has become $+U$. So whoever is flipping the field back and forth must do work in order to execute these flips, putting in at least $2 U$ of work.

For instance, the field could be controlled by the position of a second, external magnet. This magnet will also feel a magnetic force on *it* from the paramagnetic material. Flipping the field, which involves repositioning this external magnet, requires work to do because of the magnetic force from the paramagnetic material.

The fact that negative temperatures are involved is a complete red herring. Conservation of energy is built into statistical mechanics as an assumption to begin with.

Comment: Could this be an analogy with the case of a ball in a jar? If I have a ball in a jar and I suddenly invert the jar (this action requires external work), then the ball will go back down to the bottom of the jar (no, without first, staying an extremely short time on top) draining the excess energy that I supplied before.

Comment: That sounds pretty similar. I think in this analogy  you would have to somehow put the earth on the other side of the jar.

Answer (score 5):

This is because negative "magnetic orientation temperatures" properly reflect the change in number of available magnetic states with energy increase, but only of the magnetic states.  The entropy of the system as a whole remains on the increase as does the thermal temperature.

Your comment on "indefinite number of inversions" misses the fact that it takes external energy applied to the system to have this take place.

Comment: So you are telling me that the system that increases its entropy is the system that is formed by the solid, the source (of the electromagnetic field) and the thing that is inverting the field, right? In other words, I was not taking into account that the system I proposed is a non-isolated system.